# Преобразовать список в словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, список, словари

Как из списка:

```py
['2018-01-01', 'yandex', 'cpc', 100]
```

сделать такой словарь?:

```py
{'2018-01-01': {'yandex': {'cpc': 100}}}
```

Comment: Интересует общее решение для длины `N` или только для 3-х элементов?

Comment: он может быть любой длины

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [17]: l = ['2018-01-01', 'yandex', 'cpc', 100]

In [18]: last = l.pop()

In [19]: for i in reversed(l):
    ...:     last = {i: last}
    ...:

In [20]: last
Out[20]: {'2018-01-01': {'yandex': {'cpc': 100}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Через левую свертку (за неимением правой)

```py
from functools import reduce

data = ['2018-01-01', 'yandex', 'cpc', 100]

print(reduce(lambda val, key: {key: val}, reversed(data)))
```

```
{'2018-01-01': {'yandex': {'cpc': 100}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Решение через рекурсию для произвольного количества элементов:

```py
def get_d(li: list) -> dict:
    if len(li) == 1:
        return li[0]
    return {li[0]: get_d(li[1:])}


li = ['2018-01-01', 'yandex', 'cpc', 100]
print(get_d(li))
```

***stdout:***

```py
{'2018-01-01': {'yandex': {'cpc': 100}}}
```